# Python docker container use print()

Tags: python, docker

Hello I would like to use

```
print('Hello world')
```

to see what's going on with some variables, however im using Docker which means by default it's not printing anything.
Can someone tell me how I can pass these print commands to the docker container ?

Comment: You can check `docker logs` to see output of the containers

Comment: Additionally, you could run the container in non-detached mode, i.e omit the `-d` flag when doing `docker run` and output should be printed to stdout

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because Python buffers its output by default.

An easy way to change this behavior is to use the [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED): `docker run -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 <your_image>`

An other way is to call the python command with the [`-u` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should run your container with the privileged option to share /dev (therefore, sharing /dev/stdout).

This is working for me:

print.py:

```
print("Hello world")
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python
ADD print.py /
ENTRYPOINT ["python",  "/print.py"]
```

Commands:

```
$ docker build -t python-test .
$ docker run -it --privileged python-test
Hello world
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: A simple `print` statement does not need the vast power over the host that `--privileged` gives (for example it gives the power to shut down the host).  `/dev/stdout` is usually just a link to `/proc/self/fd/1`, which is to say, it's the process's normal standard output; you don't even need a device file to write there.